# Accessing the same attribute from every dictionary within a larger one?

Tags: python

I am programming a text-based adventure game in Python (by expanding on [this guy's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHPmXArK6Tg) helpful framework), and I am attempting to set up an inventory system. To do this, I have set up a dictionary full of items, each of which is its own dictionary containing things like the name and description (eventually it will store more than that, but I'm starting simple). Here's the starting inventory:

```
OBJECTNAME = ''
EXAMINE = ''

inventory = {
        'pocket watch': {
            OBJECTNAME: 'Pocket watch',
            EXAMINE: 'A broken pocket watch you once got as a birthday gift.'
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I want to write a function that lists off the objectnames (and nothing else) of each item in the inventory.

Going off of some advice from others, I tried this:

```
def player_inventory():
    for item in inventory:
        print(item[OBJECTNAME])
```

And I got the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

I imagine this sounds quite dumb, but I'm not particularly experienced in Python and I seem to be stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `print(item[OBJECTNAME])` you're returing a string object.

It can be checked with followng line:

```
for item in inventory:
        print(type(item))
```

You can change loop to iterate over items and return dictionaries by:

```
for key, value in inventory.items():
        print(value[OBJECTNAME])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
object_names = [v[OBJECTNAME] for k, v in inventory.items()]
```